# Installing Odoo on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, odoo-11

I have already install Odoo 11 on the Windows server 2012. But it works on localhost of windows server 2012. So how to redirect it to servers IP address so that I can acess Odoo from another PC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use server IP address

Comment: @Zety  Can you describe the procedure

Comment: get the server IP and use it as usual `http://SERVER_IP:8069`

Comment: @Zety  I already tried that but its not working. I also have tried reverse proxy through IIS on the server but its not working.

Comment: The odoo is on localhost and if I try to access it through another pc as http://serverip:8069 nothing comes up

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: Ok let me check that. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: Yes it works by disabling firewall. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.